# Python double backslash issue

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm using python scripts to send hundreds of thousands of insert queries to an sql server belonging to another system.

An example of my inserts:

```
"INSERT INTO ImportData (ISBNORISSNORURL, FILENAME, PDFLOCATIONS, PROCESSED) VALUES('0442019521', 'pinto_1995_245_hires.pdf', 'I:\\Collect and Process Data\\Licensing Schemes Processing\\03 Data Preparation Original\\USQ\\September-October 2010\\pinto_1995_245_hires.pdf','0');"
```

The file path string is assigned to a global:

```
PDFLOCATIONS = "I:\Collect and Process Data\Licensing Schemes Processing\03 Data Preparation Original\USQ\September-October 2010"
```

And this is then added to a dictionary consisting of name/value pairs which match up with the field and value data in the insert query.  These are converted to strings of data:

```
final_header_list = str(fields_value_list.keys()).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")

final_values_list = str(fields_value_list.values()).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")
```

Which are then added to the final insert string:

```
insert_query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES({2});'.format(TABLE,final_header_list,final_value_list)
```

Which is sent to sql server in groups of 10000.

The double backslash goes through to the database as a double backslash rather than magically converting to a single backslash.  I'm apparently not allowed to use a forward slash as an alternative.  Is there any alternative method of getting the desired single backslash on my end?  Or will the administrators of the SQL server instance have to make the change on their end?

Many thanks!

Comment: What happens if you don't escape the backslash and just put one?

Comment: why are you using double backslashs instead of a single one? using a single slash will magically convert it into a single slash. code is probably using r"string" and therefore ignoring escaped sequences

Comment: @Wil it escapes the following character

Comment: @leon would I not have to write r"string" specifically? or does python default to r"string" when assigning a = "string"?

Comment: @danspants, I assumed you did not have control over your Python code when you mentioned `on a system over which I have no control`. And no, Python does not escape the data for you. What may be happening is that when the command is sent to your database (from which we have seen no love of) it may escape your backslashes there (I mean, maybe custom code may be performing the escape). Can you check that?

Comment: @leon  It's definitely happening on the Python side, if I print out the insert queries before they get executed they contain the double backslashes.

Comment: so you need to track it down - where in the code it has single slashes and then from where on it gets double slashes. debugging 101

Comment: final_values_list = ', '.join(fields_value_list.values()) is where it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
PDFLOCATIONS = "I:\Collect and Process Data\Licensing Schemes Processing\03 Data Preparation Original\USQ\September-October 2010"
```

to

```
PDFLOCATIONS = r"I:\Collect and Process Data\Licensing Schemes Processing\03 Data Preparation Original\USQ\September-October 2010"
```

(notice the raw - `r` - indicator)

**EDIT: Trying again**

Use an ugly beast approach:

```
final_values_list = ', '.join(fields_value_list.values).replace(r"\\", "\\")
```

Thus forcing the string to have no double backslashes. Of course I'd first try replacing

```
insert_query = 'INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES({2});'.format(TABLE,final_header_list,final_value_list)
```

with

```
insert_query = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s);' % (TABLE,final_header_list,final_value_list)
```

just to be completely sure that ugly approach would not be needed.

Comment: No luck, gives the same output.

Comment: We have a winner, making it ugly has saved the day!  Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that string would not have its double backslashes convert to single backslashes is if it is a raw string -- check how it's being built.

**Edit**

Okay, now that you have actual code posted -- there are no double backslashes.  The problem is happening during the str(dict.keys()) -- it's putting in all kinds of backslashes.  You need another way of building your value string.  I will mention that you should be passing the arguments to the SQL wrapper separately and not as one string (you risk SQL injection attacks the way you are doing it).

Here is the way to build your strings without all the extra backslashes:

```
final_values_list = ', '.join(fields_value_list.values)
```

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting double backslashes.  Also no risk of an injection attack as I'm the only one using the system on an internal network, though it's obviously a good habit to get into.